# Mongoose connect: different behavior between invoking connect in a middleware

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

Why when I separate the `mongoose.connect` invocation to a different file, the program would create new connections every request? It maxed out my mongo atlas connection usage

```
//I put the connect in a middleware
//middleware.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

function connect(req, res, next) {
    mongoose.connect(db_url, {}, function (error) { //handle next })
}

module.exports = connect

//and called it in the app
app.use(mongoMiddleware)
```

The above would create tons of connection, the case is different when I invoke `connect` in the main `app.js`

```
//app.js
mongoose.connect(db_url, {}, function (error) {})
```

with the above code, the connection usage is 'stable', it doesn't fill out all the available connection.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `app.use()`
(its not needed to use the connection as a middleware,instead make a connect function and export that)

then just require the mongoose connection file in app.js

```
const mongooseConnection=require("path to the connect function")
```

the connection code would be we executed when you run the node app.